# MVVM light, CommandBinding, CommandBindingCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, wpf-commands

Как реализовать в проекте (MVVM Light) следующую конструкцию:

1. Есть несколько ViewModel и соответственно несколько View
2. В MainView хочу создать меню для вызова методов (RelayCommand или ICommand) из других ViewModel

Что я пытался сделать:
Создал интерфейс IAppCommand и соответствующий класс

```
public interface IAppCommand
{
    CommandBindingCollection CommandBinding { get; set; }
}

class AppCommand : IAppCommand
{
    public CommandBindingCollection CommandBinding { get; set; }
}
```

Во ViewModelLocator добавил

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAppCommand, AppCommand>();
```

MainViewModel выглядит так:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    public IAppCommand AppCommands { get; set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService, IAppCommand appCommand)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
         AppCommands = appCommand;

        CommandBinding customCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
            CustomRoutedCommand, ExecutedCustomCommand, CanExecuteCustomCommand);
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MainViewModel), customCommandBinding);
        AppCommands.CommandBinding.Add(customCommandBinding);

    }

    private void CanExecuteCustomCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void ExecutedCustomCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test Can");
    }

    public ICommand CustomRoutedCommand => new RelayCommand(messageBox);

    private void messageBox()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

Согласно [Источник](https://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/commandbindings-in-mvvm/) добавил свойство зависимости

```
public class AttachedProperties
{
    #region - RegisterCommandBindings Attached Property -
    public static DependencyProperty RegisterCommandBindingsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RegisterCommandBindings", typeof(CommandBindingCollection), typeof(AttachedProperties),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnRegisterCommandBindingChanged));

    public static void SetRegisterCommandBindings(UIElement element, CommandBindingCollection value)
    {
        if(element != null)
            element.SetValue(RegisterCommandBindingsProperty, value);
    }
    public static CommandBindingCollection GetRegisterCommandBindings(UIElement element)
    {
        return (element != null ? (CommandBindingCollection)element.GetValue(RegisterCommandBindingsProperty) : null);
    }
    private static void OnRegisterCommandBindingChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            CommandBindingCollection bindings = e.NewValue as CommandBindingCollection;
            if (bindings != null)
            {
                element.CommandBindings.AddRange(bindings);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

В MainView добавил

```
<Window x:Class ...
model:AttachedProperties.RegisterCommandBindings="{Binding AppCommands.CommandBinding}">
```

Как теперь в меню добавить эту команду "CustomRoutedCommand"

```
<Menu>
       <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="????????"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Или это можно сделать как то более элегантно?

Comment: `Command="CustomRoutedCommand"`?

Comment: Нет. Так не работает

Comment: DataContext установлен?

Comment: Это Menu, оно находится вне визуального дерева. Биндиться придётся через proxy класс

Comment: @AntonShakalo, Menu вне дерева? Это же не ContextMenu

Comment: Конечно. DataContext установлен

Comment: @ГошаБатарейкин, показывайте где и как

Comment: <Window x:Class ...  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}